# nvidia-smi has failed because it couldn't communicate

Tags: drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my System76 machine with a GeForce GTX 750 Ti. I was trying to install CUDA when I realized the driver wasn't properly installed.

I've tried multiple approaches to installing the driver, including nvidia runfiles, software-properties and the [System76 drivers](https://launchpad.net/system76-driver), but in all cases, when I run nvidia-smi afterward I get the same error:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

When I run lspci, I see (among other things):

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
```

I can't run any of the CUDA samples.

Some other things that I noticed:

- modinfo does not have nvidia (except nvidiafb, which I've read is unrelated).
- I don't have /proc/driver/nvidia

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've burned way too much time on this.