# NVIDIA-SMI says it failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently install Ubuntu 18.04 and installed NVIDIA driver but they don't seem to be loading.

I had to make the following edit to my grub file to make things boot properly as per [this little guide](http://pclub.in/2017/01/06/Linux-on-Asus-ROG.html).

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 acpi_osi=Linux i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 idle=nomwait"`

This is what my command outputs currently give:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.


$ nvidia-settings 
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension)


$ name -r
4.15.0-38-generic


$ lshw -c display
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f4000000-f4ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff memory:70000000-71ffffff ioport:a000(size=128) memory:f5000000-f507ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:b000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f8000000-f8ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:c000(size=128) memory:f9000000-f907ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.



$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
06:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
09:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
0a:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)


$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  4
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
input_leds             16384  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
eeepc_wmi              16384  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
video                  45056  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm                   598016  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_intel          40960  7
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
aesni_intel           188416  0
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd                    81920  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
mei_me                 40960  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
intel_cstate           20480  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
joydev                 24576  0
wmi                    24576  4 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 usbhid,hid_generic
drm_kms_helper        172032  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
igb                   212992  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
e1000e                249856  0
dca                    16384  1 igb
drm                   401408  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 igb
ahci                   36864  2
ptp                    20480  2 igb,e1000e
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler        53248  1 ipmi_devintf
```

I installed the drivers via `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` as per [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

EDIT: Here are some more command outputs:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia-driver-
nvidia-driver-390                install

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
<blank>

$ ls /lib/modules/*/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
```

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia-driver-`, `lsmod | grep nvidia` and `ls /lib/modules/*/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko`?

Comment: @Hermann I've added these outputs as an edit to the post. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: The installation looks good so far. The module is in place. But it is not loaded. What does `dmesg | grep nvidia` say?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404529/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate

Answer (score 1):

I just recently had same issue. To make it work what I did was:

- Deleted all nvidia packages via synaptic (maybe it's enough to `sudo apt purge nvidia*`)
- Restarted PC
- Installed nvidia-drivers-396 (in your case nvidia-driver-390)
- Restarted PC
- Executed:

  - `sudo prime-select nvidia`
  - `sudo prime-select intel`
  - `sudo prime-select nvidia`
- Logged out (restart should do same thing) and it was working.